# Scala: multiple thread pools overhead when using Akka and Netty together

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka, netty

I am designing an asynchronous networking application, where I need to use Netty and Akka (local actors only) together. Netty requires a NioEventLoopGroup instance, which creates a thread pool. Akka creates its own thread pool within ActorSytem instance. The application will run on a 6-core machine. So my question is: is it a good idea to have one thread pool for both Akka and Netty? I mean, if there are more threads than physical cores on the machine, then CPU thread context switching will occur frequently, which will impact application's performance in high load situations. Or am I wrong and having multiple thread pools is totally OK?
And the second question: how can I make Akka and Netty both share one common thread pool, if it is necessary? I can create an ActorSystem instance with a provided ExecutionContext, but I could not find a proper constructor for NioEventLoopGroup().

Comment: It appears that I can use ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService() to create an ExecutionContext instance from Netty's EventLoopGroup, and pass it to ActorSystem.apply(...). So the second question is answered, but the first one still remains.

Comment: First of all, you should measure. Also, Netty threadpools will usually do IO-bound tasks, while the ActorSystem will do probably other tasks with different characteristics. In fact it is usually a good idea to configure an ActorSystem with multiple dispatchers (thread-pools) not just one. Context switching is less of an issue, what matters is proper resource isolation of the parts that have different characteritics (IO vs CPU, short tasks vs. long tasks, etc.)

Comment: @EndreVarga Thank you for your comment. Maybe you're right, and it is not an issue at all. In Akka's performance-related part of the docs it is also recommended to have multiple dispatchers for different needs. But I cannot find a real-life example of the properly configured system with different dispatchers meant to be used under high load. So I have these theoretical recommendations, which contradict my feelings that in practice this can lead to CPU context-switching overhead. So I am beginning to believe that my own measurement is indeed the only way for me to make a decision.